# Сохранение изображений, приходящих через HTTP

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Нужно сделать приложение для доски обьявлений на *Android*.

Изображения товара как-то загружаю, но как сохранить их? 
Вообще стоит ли их сохранять?

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, у вас есть приложение с доской объявлений и вам нужно подгружать картинки в ленту объявлений - логика примерно такая?

Сохранять картинки никуда, естественно, не нужно, если вы их не собираетесь кэшировать и переиспользовать. Но лучше отдать это управление автоматически другим библиотекам:

Допустим, что у вас есть примерно следующая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewId" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Тогда загрузить картинку можно вот так:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);

String urlOfImage = "http://www.rosphoto.com/images/u/articles/1510/5_7.jpg";

Glide
    .with(getContext())
    .load(urlOfImage)
    .into(image);
```

В примере использована библиотека [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Или же можно вообще без сторонних библиотек:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);

String urlOfImage = "http://www.rosphoto.com/images/u/articles/1510/5_7.jpg";

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```